# Create an array of objects with a status

Tags: knockout.js

I have a hierarchal structure in knockoutjs. This structure can go to N deep but in everyday use it would not go past 4 deep. It roughly looks like this.

```
var model = function(){
    self.Id = ko.observable();   
    self.Status = ko.observable();
    self.Children = ko.oberservaleArray();
}
```

I would like to create a computed function that gives me a flat list of model objects that are in a particular status.

I would do this similar to for only one level deep.

```
self.SomeStatus = ko.computed(function() {
     ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Children(), function(item) {
         if(item.Status() === "SomeStatus")
             return item;
     });
}
```

How can this be implemented to return an array of models for N level deep that have this same status?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a recursive function which walks through your tree and adds every node to an array, similar to the following:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray();
function flattenList(flattenedList, currentChildList){
    var childCount = currentChildList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
        flattenedList.push(currentChildList[i]);
        flattenList(flattenedList, currentChildList[i].children());
    }
}
this.flattenedList = ko.computed(function(){
    var flattenedList = [];
    flattenList(flattenedList, self.items());
    return flattenedList;
});
```

The children in this case is defined by the `ItemViewModel`, like so:

```
function ItemViewModel(name){
    var self = this;

    self.name = name;
    self.children = ko.observableArray();
}
```

Do be aware that it will iterate through your whole tree every time the `items` observable or any `children` observables change. I have written a jsfiddle for it, which you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/T42LV/.

Comment: Of course, just add a filter in the for-loop, which makes sure it only push those items which have the status you're looking for.